# to show the loading bar till the fetched

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I am trying to show the loading bar until it is fetched. so I chose to use the material UI loading bar. I created this method to show the loading bar renderProgressBar.
But when I was trying to render It was giving this error:

> `invariant.js:42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is
>   invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
>   class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

I tried debugging in the console but nothing helped.
can you tell me how to fix it by using the code snippet below?

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-actions-hntd8

```or-tag-here
  renderProgressBar = () => {
        console.log(
            'store.getState().fetchingMessage---->',
            store.getState().fetchingMessage
        );

        if (store.getState().fetchingMessage) {
            console.log(
                'inside if rstore.getState().fetchingMessage---->',
                store.getState().fetchingMessage
            );

            return (
                <div

                >
                    <LinearProgress />
                </div>
            );
        }
    };
```

Comment: You're not returning anything if your _if_ statement evaluates `false`

Comment: How are you importing the LinearProgress? it looks like this could be the issue, AS @chautelly said your if statement is retuning undefined

Comment: As others have mentioned, you seem to have your LinearProgress is not being imported correctly.
https://material-ui.com/api/linear-progress/

Answer (score 0):

LinearProgress is not being imported correctly that's why you are getting the Invariant Violation.

As stated here: https://material-ui.com/api/linear-progress/

You want to use either of these imports:

```
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';
// or
import { LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
```

You seem to have `import {LinearProgress} from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';` which doesn't return undefined because it's not exporting a named module called LinearProgress under core folder.

Comment: hey can you give code comments, its hard to understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Hey @zf I've refactored a little of your codesandbox and i found mainly two issues:

- The first one is as we said before that you are importing **LinearProgress** the wrong way.
- The other issue that ive found is that you have unmatching versions of **react** and **reactDOM**.

Then i've just added the calls to get the clases and the styles and there you got it, check the codesandbox and feel free to ask questions:

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-async-actions-i4vqf

Remem,ber to read the docs when you are stuck, this is the main flow to solve your issues. [LinearProgressDocs](https://material-ui.com/es/components/progress/)

Comment: hey can you give code comments, its hard to understand :(

Comment: Ive added some comments on the **ProgressBar** component that the thing that changed in your code, the other issue was just updating your **reactDOM** module that was **different** that the **react** library that was **16.10**